# How to add several values for a single key in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, selenium, registry, dos, doskey

I'm trying to add an entry for AutoRun with value `doskey selenium=java -jar C:\dev\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`. However the AutoRun key has already a value `(if %ANSICON_VER%==^%ANSICON_VER^% "C:\dev\ansi166\x64\ansicon" -p)`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: The values of the Run registry key have names.  Pick a name, any name, as long as it doesn't match one that already exists.

Comment: @eryksun thank you! I hope you would write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoRun` value is the command line to run. You could simply append another command using the `&` operator. For example:

```
(if %ANSICON_VER%==^%ANSICON_VER^% "C:\dev\ansi166\x64\ansicon" -p) & (doskey selenium=java -jar C:\dev\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar)
```

Or replace the command with your own batch file, e.g. `("%LocalAppData%\autorun.cmd")`.

Bear in mind that most `system` implementations (including Microsoft's) for some reason don't use the `/D` option to disable `AutoRun` commands; they just run a command using `%ComSpec% /c`. You can check/set a guard environment variable to avoid running doskey multiple times.